# SQL Query stopped working and cant figure out why

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

Basically I am using MS Access 2013 to import all active work items that are  assigned to a specific group from an API and select the data into 2 new tables (Requests & Request_Tasks).

I then have a form sourced from a query to select specific fields from the 2 tables.

Until yesterday it was working with no problems and nothing has changed.

All of the data appears in the 2 tables so the import from the API works fine.

When it comes to the query selecting the data from the 2 tables (Which are already populated with the correct data) the query returns only data from Requests table with blank fields instead of data from Request_Tasks.

The strange part is that out of 28 active work items it returns 24 correctly and the last 4 are having the problem.

Every new task added to the group has the problem also.

Query is below.

```
SELECT 
Request_Tasks.RQTASK_Number, 
Request_Tasks.Request_Number, 
Requests.Task, Requests.Entity, 
Request_Tasks.Description, 
Request_Tasks.Request_Status, 
Requests.Requested_for_date, 
Request_Tasks.Work_On_Date, 
Request_Tasks.Estimated_Time, 
Request_Tasks.Actual_Time_Analysis, 
Request_Tasks.Offers_Built, 
Request_Tasks.Number_of_links_Opened, 
Request_Tasks.Number_of_Links_Extended, 
Request_Tasks.Number_Of_links_closed, 
Request_Tasks.Build_Allocated_to, 
Request_Tasks.Buld_Review_Allocated_to, 
Request_Tasks.Keying_Allocated_to, 
Request_Tasks.Keying_Approval_allocated_to, 
Request_Tasks.Actual_Build_Time, 
Request_Tasks.Actual_Stakeholder_Support, 
Request_Tasks.Task_Completed_Date

FROM Request_Tasks 

RIGHT JOIN Requests 
  ON Request_Tasks.Request_Number = Requests.Request_Number

WHERE (((Request_Tasks.Task_Completed_Date)>=Date() 
Or (Request_Tasks.Task_Completed_Date) Is Null) 
AND ((Requests.Task)<>"7" 
And (Requests.Task)<>"8" And (Requests.Task)<>"9")) 
OR (((Request_Tasks.Task_Completed_Date)>=Date() 
Or (Request_Tasks.Task_Completed_Date) Is Null) 
AND ((Requests.Task)<>"7" 
And (Requests.Task)<>"8" 
And (Requests.Task)<>"9"))

ORDER BY Request_Tasks.Work_On_Date Is Null DESC , Request_Tasks.Work_On_Date, Requests.Entity Is Null DESC , Requests.Task;
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The query is using `RIGHT JOIN`, which means rows from `Requests` table is always reported even if there is no corresponding entry in `Request_tasks` table.

A full example is here http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join_right.asp

In your case, most likely somechange might have happened during data load/API and `Request_tasks` table is not being populated. That is the reason you see blank data for fields from that table.

Solution

- Manually check data for 4 faulty records in `Request_tasks` table.
- Ensure keys in both table `request_number` are matching including data type and any leading space/non printable characters (if they are string type of data) for faulty records.

Query seems fine, its more of issue with data based on problem statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this hasn't helped. The API import has worked and all the data in the tables is how it should be. Its as if the query doesn't recognise the join. Creating a new query gives the same result. It seems like 1 record has a problem and every record after that is the same but I don't know what it could be

Comment: It might be that for those 4 requests from `Request_Tasks` the value of field, `Request_Number` is not found in `Requests` table

Comment: Are you using auto number in table? If so, what data type is auto number?